# Where is localStorage object is defined?

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage, session-storage, web-storage

Where the browser `localStorage` variable defined and how is that possible we can access `window.localStorage` object through a global browser variable `localStorage`?Seems like this browser behaviour is not described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#window.localstorage) and in any sources.

Comment: MDN - [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: because it is built into the language? Just like how location, history, and other things are defined.

Comment: WHATWG- [Web storage](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html)